# javascript regex pattern to match words, with custom word boundary

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match words in a string using regex in javascript.

Lets say the string is "I have c++ as a skill". I now want to count the number of occurrences of the "c++" substring. I do not want to match if the string is "I have c++test" or similar. So I need to check for word boundaries and include some special character like + and #.

I have the following code:

```
var str = "I have c++ as a skill, but I do not have c++test as a skill";

var regex = new RegExp("(?<![\\w+#])c\\+\\+(?![\\w+#])", "g");

count = (str.match(regex) || []).length; 

console.log(count);
```

Expected result is "1".

This is failing on the line var regex... with the error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<![\w+#])c\+\+(?![\w+#])/: Invalid group
```

I fail to see what I need to change to make my boundary work, can anyone help me?

Comment: You can use Regex literals, they are easier to read because they do not need the double escaping: `/(?<![\w+#])c\+\+(?![\w+#])/`

Comment: In JS: `Lookbehind is not supported at all. Lookahead is fully supported.`

Comment: If I were you, I would use: \sc\\+\\+\s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
var regex = new RegExp("([^\\w#]|^)c\\+\\+(?=[^\\w#]|$)", "g");
```

Comment: Very close, I might have been vague on my question, but I need to check for word boundaries, as well as whitespace. This will not match str = "c++ c++" as 2, only 1.